# Representing one diagonal of Pascal's triangle using special sums coming from a different diagonal

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $m, n$ be any fixed natural numbers. Is it true that infinitely many elements of the sequence $\binom{m+k}{m}_{k=1,2,3,...}$ ( as well as of the sequence $\left(\binom{m+k}{m}-1\right)_{k=1,2,3,...})$ are representable as the sums of different elements of the sequence $\binom{n+k}{n}_{k=1,2,3,...}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed $n$, the expression $\binom{n+k}n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $k$ with no fixed prime divisor. A theorem of Kamke (referenced in the [first paragraph here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/warpoly.pdf)) says that there exists $x$ such that all sufficiently large integers are the sum of $s$ values of $\binom{n+k}n$. Of course this will include, for fixed $m$, all but finitely many values $\binom{m+j}m$.

Comment: Greg, thank you for your valuable information. In my case the $s$ values should be evaluated in different $s$ points, which is not assumed in that paper. May be the Waring's polynomial problem holds true in such form also?

Comment: Yes, that extra distinctness criterion almost always comes for free in Waring-type problems. The method gives an asymptotic formula for the number of representations, and also asymptotic formulas/upper bounds for the number of representations where there are repetitions; subtracting the two shows that most such representations have distinct terms.

Comment: Greg, I am sorry for disturbing you one more time. So far I couldn’t find any paper related to the asymptotic formulas/upper bounds for the number of representations where there are repetitions (for Waring’s polynomial problem). Please, can you give any references? May be there are papers or books where the Waring’s polynomial problem is stated directly in that form i.e. with x1 < x2 < …<xs ?